# Getting "Invalid access token code 43" with iOS Firebase Facebook SDK after my app was disabled

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, facebook-access-token, facebook-test-users

I'm experiencing an issue with the `Firebase` `Facebook SDK` in my iOS app. After my app was disabled, I'm unable to connect with test users and keep receiving the `Invalid access token code 43` error. I have already gone through the `Firebase` and `Facebook` documentation but couldn't find a solution.

Has anyone else faced a similar problem with the `Firebase` `Facebook SDK` after their app was disabled? Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried the following troubleshooting steps but with no success:

1. Verified that my app's credentials in `Firebase` and `Facebook` are correctly set.
2. Checked the permissions and access tokens for the test users, ensuring they have the necessary permissions.
3. Confirmed that the test users are still associated with my app.

I'm not sure if there are any additional steps or configurations needed to resolve this issue after the app was temporarily disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the documentation and troubleshooting steps, I discovered that the problem was related to a **Facebook app restriction**. **The test user can only access to public_profile and email but he can't perform the sign-in or sign-up process.**

To resolve the issue, I reached out to Facebook support and explained the situation. They were able to assist me in removing the app restriction, allowing the test user to connect successfully.

If you're facing a similar problem, I recommend reaching out to Facebook support directly and providing them with detailed information about your situation. They should be able to help you resolve the issue.

**I hope this helps!**

Comment: can you please share more details about how you contacted Facebook and what you said to them? we got in the same situation as you are. we Appealed so many times, but they are not removing the app's restrictions.

Comment: Joining @JeetRajPut request. None of the support channels are working actually.

Comment: @TRMIMI can you please provide information?